Verification of Reservation Price and Optimal Bid/Ask Calculations in Avellaneda-Stoikov Model for Perpetual Futures
Background:
I am implementing an algorithmic market-making strategy based on the Avellaneda-Stoikov model, specifically tailored for perpetual futures, and I have some questions regarding the model adjustments I made for working with perpetual futures.
Key Variables and Parameters:

S: Current mid-price of the asset.
q: Current inventory position (positive for long, negative for short).
σ: Volatility of the asset price, estimated using a rolling window of price data.
γ: Risk aversion coefficient.
α: Order arrival rate, estimated from market data.
κ: Order book depth parameter, estimated from market data.
τ: Fraction of time remaining in the trading period.
δ: Expected funding payment adjustment.

Reservation Price (r):
r = S − qγστ − δ

Funding payment adjustment:

Accounts for the expected funding costs or payments in perpetual futures.
Calculated as:
$$\delta = q \cdot r_f \cdot \left(\frac{t_f}{T_f}\right)$$, where $r_f$ is the expected funding rate, $t_f$ is the time until funding and $T_f$ is the funding interval.



Optimal Spread ($s^*$):
The optimal spread balances the trade-off between profit per trade and the probability of execution:
$$s^* = \gamma\sigma\tau + \frac{2}{\gamma}\ln\left(1 + \frac{\gamma}{\kappa}\right)$$

First Term ($\gamma\sigma\tau$): Increases the spread with greater risk aversion, volatility, or remaining time.
Second Term ($\frac{2}{\gamma}\ln\left(1 + \frac{\gamma}{\kappa}\right)$): Adjusts for market liquidity through $\kappa$.

Optimal Bid and Ask Prices ($p_b$ and $p_a$):
Positioned around the reservation price:
$$p_b = r - \frac{s^*}{2}$$
$$p_a = r + \frac{s^*}{2}$$
Questions:

Are the above formulas for the reservation price and optimal spread correctly derived and applied in the context of the Avellaneda-Stoikov model? Specifically, does the inclusion of the funding payment adjustment (δ) correctly modify the reservation price for perpetual futures?
In the case of a perpetual (infinite) trading horizon, is it appropriate to set the time left fraction () to 1? If not, how should  be adjusted or interpreted when the strategy does not have a fixed end time?
Are there additional considerations or modifications needed when applying the Avellaneda-Stoikov model to perpetual futures markets as opposed to spot markets?


I guess you are referring to section 2.3, which drops T, but is forced to introduce a discount factor (omega) or the integral does not converge. The HJB equation in 3.1 won't have a (u_t) term, but the paper does not develop it. You could try to do it, following https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4604181/understanding-hjb-equation-for-the-infinite-horizon-consumption-control-problem If you do, then it will be easier to see if your intuition is correct.
